# Resizing .svg image using 'convert' function of ImageMagick suite produces empty images

Tags: svg, image-resizing

I have created a quick .svg of the StackOverflow logo, which looks like this:

[image: Original SVG]

With the following data in the .svg file itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="256.000000pt" height="256.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 256.000000 256.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.14, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,256.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1095 2549 c-464 -62 -875 -402 -1029 -850 -57 -168 -78 -379 -58
-579 44 -421 317 -806 706 -995 187 -91 340 -125 566 -125 222 0 378 34 558
120 142 68 239 138 352 250 113 113 184 213 250 353 95 199 127 366 117 622
-8 221 -61 406 -167 584 -70 118 -118 177 -225 279 -178 170 -382 278 -618
326 -95 20 -356 28 -452 15z m695 -466 c0 -5 22 -135 49 -291 27 -155 46 -284
42 -286 -3 -2 -27 -7 -53 -11 -44 -7 -47 -6 -53 16 -17 74 -95 552 -91 557 5
5 65 18 94 21 6 0 12 -2 12 -6z m-240 -344 c80 -117 153 -224 163 -240 l18
-28 -42 -31 -43 -31 -18 23 c-10 13 -84 121 -165 241 l-148 219 35 29 c19 16
39 29 45 29 5 0 75 -95 155 -211z m-195 -219 c132 -78 242 -143 244 -145 2 -2
-9 -25 -23 -50 -25 -41 -29 -44 -49 -34 -51 26 -467 281 -472 289 -7 11 43 92
53 87 4 -3 115 -69 247 -147z m-107 -221 c152 -40 279 -73 281 -75 5 -5 -30
-104 -37 -104 -12 0 -526 140 -543 148 -15 6 -15 12 -3 55 8 26 17 47 20 47 3
0 130 -32 282 -71z m-458 -384 l0 -265 405 0 405 0 0 265 0 265 40 0 40 0 0
-310 0 -310 -495 0 -495 0 0 310 0 310 50 0 50 0 0 -265z m390 165 c124 -11
245 -23 269 -27 l43 -6 -5 -50 c-4 -27 -8 -51 -9 -53 -2 -1 -134 9 -294 23
l-291 26 4 46 c7 66 10 72 35 66 13 -2 124 -14 248 -25z m300 -255 l0 -55
-295 0 -295 0 0 55 0 55 295 0 295 0 0 -55z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

And I'm attempting to resize it to 30x30 like so:

```
convert stackoverflow-4-xxl.svg -resize 30x30 stackoverflow-4-xxl_s.svg
```

But this produces an empty image (even though data is still present, as seen in the .svg file itself, below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="30" height="30">
<g style="" transform="scale(1.25,1.25)">
<g style="fill:#000000;stroke:none;" transform="matrix(0.1 0 0 -0.1 0 256)">
<g style="" transform="matrix(0.1 0 0 -0.1 0 256)">
  <path d="M1095 2549 c-464 -62 -875 -402 -1029 -850 -57 -168 -78 -379 -58 -579 44 -421 317 -806 706 -995 187 -91 340 -125 566 -125 222 0 378 34 558 120 142 68 239 138 352 250 113 113 184 213 250 353 95 199 127 366 117 622 -8 221 -61 406 -167 584 -70 118 -118 177 -225 279 -178 170 -382 278 -618 326 -95 20 -356 28 -452 15z m695 -466 c0 -5 22 -135 49 -291 27 -155 46 -284 42 -286 -3 -2 -27 -7 -53 -11 -44 -7 -47 -6 -53 16 -17 74 -95 552 -91 557 5 5 65 18 94 21 6 0 12 -2 12 -6z m-240 -344 c80 -117 153 -224 163 -240 l18 -28 -42 -31 -43 -31 -18 23 c-10 13 -84 121 -165 241 l-148 219 35 29 c19 16 39 29 45 29 5 0 75 -95 155 -211z m-195 -219 c132 -78 242 -143 244 -145 2 -2 -9 -25 -23 -50 -25 -41 -29 -44 -49 -34 -51 26 -467 281 -472 289 -7 11 43 92 53 87 4 -3 115 -69 247 -147z m-107 -221 c152 -40 279 -73 281 -75 5 -5 -30 -104 -37 -104 -12 0 -526 140 -543 148 -15 6 -15 12 -3 55 8 26 17 47 20 47 3 0 130 -32 282 -71z m-458 -384 l0 -265 405 0 405 0 0 265 0 265 40 0 40 0 0 -310 0 -310 -495 0 -495 0 0 310 0 310 50 0 50 0 0 -265z m390 165 c124 -11 245 -23 269 -27 l43 -6 -5 -50 c-4 -27 -8 -51 -9 -53 -2 -1 -134 9 -294 23 l-291 26 4 46 c7 66 10 72 35 66 13 -2 124 -14 248 -25z m300 -255 l0 -55 -295 0 -295 0 0 55 0 55 295 0 295 0 0 -55z"/>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

So, just to see if resizing to the same size produces the original image (or therabouts), I did:

```
convert stackoverflow-4-xxl.svg -resize 256x256 stackoverflow-4-xxl_m.svg
```

And this *still* produced an empty image, with the .svg data identical except for:

```
<svg width="256" height="256">
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I do not have anything to do with SVG but I thought the idea it was a vector image and could be resized without loosing information. I understood this to mean it was scaled by the display program. So I would try saving it as a png and see what happens.

Comment: I know what you're saying, I should be able to resize it with the CSS/HTML I'm using it with, but I'm having difficulty. So my thinking is that I resize the .svg to the same size as the .svgs I have that currently already work, and the CSS etc. should work fine. Probably not the best way to approach it, but it's either that or make no progress at the moment.

Comment: Just a quick test using html and this resizes it in my browser OK: <img src="logo.svg" width="30"> Do you have some css/html code to post? The alternative is to try Inkscape directly which I think Imagemagick uses anyway.

Comment: I wonder if it is your setup as this worked for me convert "logo.svg" -resize 30x30 "smalllogo.svg" although it seems to have changed it to a png? in my case: xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeEAQAAAD

Comment: Imagemagick is not the right tool to go from vector to vector formats. It will rasterize the image. The final svg file will just be a lot of dots.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a program.

Either:

1. hand edit the SVG. Change the `width` and `height` to `30px`.

   ```
   <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 256.000000 256.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">...
   ```
2. Or if you want to style its size with CSS, just remove the `width` and `height`.

   ```
   <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 256.000000 256.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">...
   ```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was after.